# is it possible to re-tweet & favourite from multiple user accounts?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, tweets

I have 50 user accounts in Twitter.
I want to make a script that retrieve user tweets(e.g. from @username) and I want to retrieve all tweets & Re-tweet from my all (50) accounts at once.

Is it possible or not? If so then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get them with the API watch the developers site:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: this is only used for retrieve user tweets not for re-tweet have you verified that? i want to Re-tweet a tweet from multiple user accounts at once.

Answer (score 0):

This one was too long to enter in a comment. But you still need [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline).

In an important part of the documentation:

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent
>   Tweets. **Native retweets of other statuses by the user is included in
>   this total**, regardless of whether include_rts is set to false when
>   requesting this resource.

If you scroll down further on that previous link, you'll see the example they have shown and within that an important field that you're interested in is `"retweeted": false,`.

If the tweet you obtain from that specific user was written by them it'll show `false`, if it's a re-tweet from another person's it'll show as `true`. You can utilize that to determine if it's a re-tweet or not.